# jQuery Mobile loses form data when page is manually reloaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a jQuery Mobile page that accepts some form data from the page before it and prints it out. Normally when I click "refresh" on my browser, I'm asked if I'd like to resubmit the form data. That's the desired effect in my case. Instead, when I try to refresh the page, it doesn't ask me about resubmitting the form data. All form data is lost.

If I remove the link to jQuery Mobile from my page (but leave the link to jQuery), everything works fine again.

The form on the initial page has data-ajax set to false. A script validates the form and then submits it using .submit().

I've searched all over for a question similar to mine, and am baffled that nothing has turned up.